# Division by zero after removing factor.

Tags: divisibility

I know that anything divided by zero is undefined and I understand why. However, I have just discovered this sum, and it confused me greatly. Could anyone explain what is going on here:

$$x-x=0$$
$$x(1-1)=0$$
$$x=\frac{0}{(1-1)}$$
$$x=\frac{0}{0}$$

For example when 'x=3':

$$3-3=0$$
$$3(1-1)=0$$
$$3=\frac{0}{(1-1)}$$
$$3=\frac{0}{0}$$

Comment: The forbidden act was: dividing by 0=1-1.

Comment: If you know division by $0$ is undefined, why would you assume you're getting sane results, after dividing by $(1-1)$?

Comment: Thou shall not divide by zero. 11th commandment..

Answer (score 1):

Dividing a number by zero results in an undefined expression. This is true however you write zero. $\displaystyle 0, x - x,\cos \left({\frac \pi 2}\right),\ln 1, \text {etc.}$ all are the same number.